# Is rate limiting delay included in nginx $request_time?

Tags: nginx, http

If requests are delayed by nginx rate limiting (rate limit exceeded, but within burst rate), is this delay included in the nginx `$request_time` total?

The nginx docs state that `$request_time` is ["time elapsed since the first bytes were read from the client"](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_time)

If a request is delayed, is that before or after request bytes are read from the client? I assume *after*, since rate limiting can be based on request headers, etc.

Is there a way to separate total request time and time spent specifically on sending/receiving network communication to/from the client?

**Note**: I am aware of `$upstream_response_time`, and am logging that. I specifically am concerned with differentiating specific operations within nginx (caching, rate limiting, etc), and client-side network communications.

Answer (score 1):

So, in my testing, nginx `$request_time` logging **does** reflect delay due to rate limiting.

Client:

```
wrk --timeout 20s -d 20 -t 79 -c 80 https://zapazoid.vistashare.net/Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js
```

Config:

`nodelay` removed from static rate limiting, and rate limit to `1r/s`, burst set to `80r/s`.

Test Results:

```
❯ wrk --timeout 20s -d 20 -t 79 -c 80 https://zapazoid.vistashare.net/Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js
Running 20s test @ https://zapazoid.vistashare.net/Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js
  79 threads and 80 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     9.97s     5.97s   19.93s    56.10%
    Req/Sec     0.27      1.57    10.00     97.56%
  41 requests in 20.10s, 140.14KB read
Requests/sec:      2.04
Transfer/sec:      6.97KB
```

Nginx logs showed requests being delayed:

```
2021/11/29 15:40:23 [warn] 2608#2608: *355 delaying request, excess: 78.992, by zone "static-corp", client: 10.100.2.130, server: zapazoid.vistashare.net, request: "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "zapazoid.vistashare.net"
```

Access logging was configured as:

```
    log_format apm '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '             
                   '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '                   
                   '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '                    
                   '$request_time $upstream_response_time '                 
                   '$upstream_cache_status';
```

and access logs showed climbing `$request_time` values (3rd value from end), as requests were increasingly delayed to fall into the configured limit:

```
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:46:51 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 0.001 0.004 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:46:51 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 0.496 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:46:52 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 0.995 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:46:52 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 1.495 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:46:53 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 1.999 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:46:53 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 2.495 0.004 MISS
...
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:47:02 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 11.467 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:47:03 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 11.964 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:47:03 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 12.466 0.004 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:47:04 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 12.963 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:47:04 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 13.460 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:47:05 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 13.961 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:47:05 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 14.452 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:47:06 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 14.946 0.000 MISS
10.100.2.130 - - [29/Nov/2021:15:47:06 -0500] "GET /Static/jquery.jnotify-1.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3098 "-" "-" 15.446 0.000 MISS
```